# How to call a onload function inside javascript in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, ionic4

I am importing a jquery game to my ionic app version 4 which is based on Angular 6. I am able to import all the required js and css files to angular.
But as the game starts using

> game.onload()

in windows.load function, the same i tried in ngInit() in Angular 6. But its not working! How could i call a function which is defined iniside a variable in javascript using Angular 6.

My JS code is:

```
var game = {
    data: {
        score: 0,
        steps: 0,
        start: !1,
        newHiScore: !1,
        muted: !1
    },
    resources: [{
        name: "bg",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/bg.png"
    }, {
        name: "clumsy",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/clumsy.png"
    }, {
        name: "pipe",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/pipe.png"
    }, {
        name: "logo",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/logo.png"
    }, {
        name: "ground",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/ground.png"
    }, {
        name: "gameover",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/gameover.png"
    }, {
        name: "gameoverbg",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/gameoverbg.png"
    }, {
        name: "hit",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/hit.png"
    }, {
        name: "getready",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/getready.png"
    }, {
        name: "new",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/new.png"
    }, {
        name: "share",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/share.png"
    }, {
        name: "tweet",
        type: "image",
        src: "../data/img/tweet.png"
    }, {
        name: "theme",
        type: "audio",
        src: "../data/bgm/"
    }, {
        name: "hit",
        type: "audio",
        src: "../data/sfx/"
    }, {
        name: "lose",
        type: "audio",
        src: "../data/sfx/"
    }, {
        name: "wing",
        type: "audio",
        src: "../data/sfx/"
    }],
    onload: function() {
        return me.video.init(900, 600, {
            wrapper: "screen",
            scale: "auto",
            scaleMethod: "fit"
        }) ? (me.audio.init("mp3,ogg"), void me.loader.preload(game.resources, this.loaded.bind(this))) : void alert("Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.")
    },
    loaded: function() {
        me.state.set(me.state.MENU, new game.TitleScreen), me.state.set(me.state.PLAY, new game.PlayScreen), me.state.set(me.state.GAME_OVER, new game.GameOverScreen), me.input.bindKey(me.input.KEY.SPACE, "fly", !0), me.input.bindKey(me.input.KEY.M, "mute", !0), me.input.bindPointer(me.input.KEY.SPACE), me.pool.register("clumsy", game.BirdEntity), me.pool.register("pipe", game.PipeEntity, !0), me.pool.register("hit", game.HitEntity, !0), me.pool.register("ground", game.Ground, !0), me.state.change(me.state.MENU)
    }
};
```

I want to call onload function inside game variable!

My Angular Code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams  } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
//declare function helloJS();
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.page.scss'],
})
export class TestPage implements OnInit {
  id: string
  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    game.onload();
  }
}
```

i tried by above code! But error is `cannot find name game`. I know that its usual as angular cant get what game is! SO how could i call that function!
Please help me!

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Any error?

Comment: @David.. Yes `cannot find name game`..

Comment: So that's a TS error when building? Try addind `declare let game: any;` on top of your component

Comment: @David. Now the error is gone, but game is not loading! but how Declaring game in ts let angular know that it should call onload from that particular js?

Comment: Well I would assume that you added that js file in your assets and included it in the script section of your angular config, or load it manually from index.html? If not, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @David.. Yes i did! I think when i alerted from that function it is alerted! but the expected retuen value is not working!!

Comment: Well that's a different question. If you get the alert, it means that you managed to call the function, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179971/discussion-between-karthik-cp-and-david).

Comment: @David Yes i did! now error changed to  ` Can't find variable: me`.. let me check that

Comment: try to export var game from the file involved and then import the game from the module into your angular code?

Answer (score 0):

Export the variable

**Demo.js**

```
 exports.game = {
        data: {
            score: 0,
            steps: 0,
            start: !1,
            newHiScore: !1,
            muted: !1
        },
        resources: [{
            name: "bg",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/bg.png"
        }, {
            name: "clumsy",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/clumsy.png"
        }, {
            name: "pipe",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/pipe.png"
        }, {
            name: "logo",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/logo.png"
        }, {
            name: "ground",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/ground.png"
        }, {
            name: "gameover",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/gameover.png"
        }, {
            name: "gameoverbg",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/gameoverbg.png"
        }, {
            name: "hit",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/hit.png"
        }, {
            name: "getready",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/getready.png"
        }, {
            name: "new",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/new.png"
        }, {
            name: "share",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/share.png"
        }, {
            name: "tweet",
            type: "image",
            src: "../data/img/tweet.png"
        }, {
            name: "theme",
            type: "audio",
            src: "../data/bgm/"
        }, {
            name: "hit",
            type: "audio",
            src: "../data/sfx/"
        }, {
            name: "lose",
            type: "audio",
            src: "../data/sfx/"
        }, {
            name: "wing",
            type: "audio",
            src: "../data/sfx/"
        }],
        onload: function() {
            return me.video.init(900, 600, {
                wrapper: "screen",
                scale: "auto",
                scaleMethod: "fit"
            }) ? (me.audio.init("mp3,ogg"), void me.loader.preload(game.resources, this.loaded.bind(this))) : void alert("Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas.")
        },
        loaded: function() {
            me.state.set(me.state.MENU, new game.TitleScreen), me.state.set(me.state.PLAY, new game.PlayScreen), me.state.set(me.state.GAME_OVER, new game.GameOverScreen), me.input.bindKey(me.input.KEY.SPACE, "fly", !0), me.input.bindKey(me.input.KEY.M, "mute", !0), me.input.bindPointer(me.input.KEY.SPACE), me.pool.register("clumsy", game.BirdEntity), me.pool.register("pipe", game.PipeEntity, !0), me.pool.register("hit", game.HitEntity, !0), me.pool.register("ground", game.Ground, !0), me.state.change(me.state.MENU)
        }
    };
```

Then import inside your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as games from '../assets/demo';

ngOnInit() {
    games.game.onload();
  }
```